# Stumped on a new mystery cord I found in my drawer

Tags: power-supply, usb

enter image

I am sure this will be easy for most of you. I found this new (to me) cord in a drawer and can’t figure out what it might go to. There is nothing written on it aside from a “B” at one end. Since my significant other is not claiming it I am all the more curious!  Thank you.

[image: Cord photo]

Answer (score 5):

The plug is USB 3.0 Micro B. 
Maybe it goes to an external hard drive?
[image]

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy S5 uses this connector.